# Bash - while loop return to prompt

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop

I have a simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
something...
sleep 300
done
other commands...
```

Don't know if it's possible but I want the while loop to be executing in the background and execute other commands as well or returning to the prompt.

I tried `/path/to/script &`, it returns to prompt, but the loop starts only when I close the terminal window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

function doSomeThing(){
while true;do
    echo "do some thing"
    sleep 3;
done
}

doSomeThing &

echo "I am out"

# vim:ai:et:sts=4:tw=80:sw=4:
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice to put your program into a function which you can easily to manage a multiple tasks e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

task1(){
    while true
    do
        echo "task 1"
        sleep 5
    done
}

task2(){
    while true
    do
        echo "task 2"
        sleep 3
    done
}

task1 &
task2 &
```

Where `&` here stand for putting a command into a background process. From the example above `task1` and `task2` will parallelly run in a background.